# Redux state change does not trigger React component rerenders

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

this is an adapter called pairings

```
import { createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


// For now will use row ID as the Pairing_ID since it does not exist
export const pairingsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
    selectId: (pairing) => pairing.Pairing_ID.Pairing_ID
});

export const {
    selectAll: selectAllPairings,
    selectById: selectPairingById,
} = pairingsAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.pairing);
```

and this is the slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { pairingsAdapter } from './pairingsAdapter.js';


const initialState = pairingsAdapter.getInitialState({
    // You can add additional properties here if needed
});

const pairingsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'pairings',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addPairing: pairingsAdapter.addOne,
        addManyPairings: pairingsAdapter.addMany,
        removePairing: pairingsAdapter.removeOne,
    },
});

export const {
    addPairing,
    addManyPairings,
    removePairing

} = pairingsSlice.actions;

export default pairingsSlice.reducer;
```

What I am doing is iterating over this pairings to populate my app with rows, where each row contains 2 Drag n Drop cards

```
const Pairings = () => {

    // REDUX Event Queues
    const boxMakerQueue = useSelector(selectAllBoxMakers)
    const productWrapperQueue = useSelector(selectAllProductWrappers)
    const pairingsQueue = useSelector(selectAllPairings)

    return(
        <>
            {pairingsQueue.map((pairing, index) => {
                const rowID = pairing.Pairing_ID.Pairing_ID;

                // Find boxMaker, if it exists
                const boxMaker = pairing.BoxErector_WorkCenter
                    ? boxMakerQueue.find(bm => bm.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID === pairing.BoxErector_WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID)
                    : null;

                // Find productWrapper, if it exists
                const productWrapper = pairing.ProductWrapper_WorkCenter
                    ? productWrapperQueue.find(pw => pw.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID === pairing.ProductWrapper_WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID)
                    : null;

                // Set up card props
                let rightCardProps, leftCardProps;

                // If boxMaker exists, add to rightCardProps
                if (boxMaker) {
                    rightCardProps = [
                        <HorizontalCard type={'BoxMaker'} object={boxMaker}/>,
                        boxMaker.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID
                    ];
                }

                // If boxMaker does not exist, add null values
                else {
                    rightCardProps = [null, null];
                }

                // If productWrapper exists, add to leftCardProps
                if (productWrapper) {
                    leftCardProps = [
                        <HorizontalCard type={'ProductWrapper'} object={productWrapper}/>,
                        productWrapper.WorkCenter.WorkCenter_ID
                    ];
                }


                // If productWrapper and manualFeeder do not exist
                else {
                    leftCardProps = [null, null];
                }

                return (
                    <WorkCenterAssignmentEditRow
                        key={index}
                        rowID={rowID}
                        leftCardProps={leftCardProps}
                        rightCardProps={rightCardProps}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    )
```

And the rows look something like this

```
        <DroppableArea onDrop={handleCardDrop} type={itemType} area={rowID}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <DraggableCardWrapper type={itemType} cardID={leftCardID} sourceRowID={rowID}>
                        {leftCard}
                    </DraggableCardWrapper>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <DraggableCardWrapper type={itemType} cardID={rightCardID} sourceRowID={rowID}>
                        {rightCard}
                    </DraggableCardWrapper>
                </Grid>
                {isRowEmpty && <EmptyRowPlaceholder />}
            </Grid>
            <DashedHorizontalLine/>
        </DroppableArea>
```

where I am removing objects from the pairings queue on card drop

```
    const handleCardDrop = (card, monitor, area) => {
        const{cardID, sourceRowID} = card
        console.log("Dropped item:", cardID, "from source: ", sourceRowID, "to area: ", area);
        dispatch(removePairing(sourceRowID))

        console.log('pairingsQueue ->', pairingsQueue)
    };
```

Pretty much based on the console.log statement I am able to confirm that indeed I am removing stuff from Redux on card drop, the issue is that I am also trying to rerender the cards that are visible on this interaction. So effectively whenever there is a change in Redux, I need to rerender Pairings

I imagine I need to eventually use something like `reselect` to make this process more efficient, but for now I am simply trying to get my Pairings component to correctly reload whenever a state get's updated in Redux

Comment: Is `pairingsQueue` get updated in `Paring` component? I assume that the problem is the row can not removed properly from `Paring` component. is that right?